# Error by using objects in Subview loaded from XIB with ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, subview, ibaction

I just created a Xib with the Interface for an Audioplayer (Play-Button, Stop-Button, Volume-Slider, Time-Slider). I connected the Files owner to the AudioPlayerViewController and created some Outlets from the Objects and IB Action, by connecting to the ViewController.

Now I'm adding this ViewControllers View as a Subview in an UIScrollview. If I now Use one of these Objects I receive different Errors:

First the Time-Slider. There Exist a IBAction for value Changed:

```
 2013-06-23 14:14:55.448 Bookshelf[17323:907] -[__NSMallocBlock__ CurrentPlayTimeChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dd69500
2013-06-23 14:14:55.450 Bookshelf[17323:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSMallocBlock__ CurrentPlayTimeChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dd69500'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31e1d2a3 0x39cd897f 0x31e20e07 0x31e1f531 0x31d76f68 0x33d100c5 0x33d10077 0x33d10055 0x33d0f90b 0x33df0d07 0x33d0f507 0x33c2e421 0x31df26cd 0x31df09c1 0x31df0d17 0x31d63ebd 0x31d63d49 0x3592f2eb 0x33c79301 0x680dd 0x3a10fb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Second The Buttons:

```
2013-06-23 14:16:36.842 Bookshelf[17339:907] -[__NSArrayM AudioStopped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fdb1480
2013-06-23 14:16:36.844 Bookshelf[17339:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM AudioStopped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fdb1480'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31e1d2a3 0x39cd897f 0x31e20e07 0x31e1f531 0x31d76f68 0x33d100c5 0x33d1014d 0x33d100c5 0x33d10077 0x33d10055 0x33d0f90b 0x33d0fe01 0x33c385f1 0x33c25801 0x33c2511b 0x359305a3 0x359301d3 0x31df2173 0x31df2117 0x31df0f99 0x31d63ebd 0x31d63d49 0x3592f2eb 0x33c79301 0xa0dd 0x3a10fb20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Third The Volume Slider:

[image]

The ViewController .h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AudioPlayerViewController : UIViewController {
    NSURL * fileURL;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *volumeSlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *AudioStopButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *AudioPlay_PauseButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *AudioTimeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *TimeLineSlider;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL * fileURL;


- (IBAction)volumeChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)AudioStopped:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)AudioPlayPaused:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)TimeLabelPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)CurrentPlayTimeChanged:(id)sender;


@end
```

The ViewController .m :

```
#import "AudioPlayerViewController.h"

@interface AudioPlayerViewController ()

@end

@implementation AudioPlayerViewController
@synthesize volumeSlider, AudioPlay_PauseButton, TimeLineSlider, AudioTimeLabel, AudioStopButton;
@synthesize fileURL;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)volumeChanged:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"NEW VOL");

}

- (IBAction)AudioStopped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"STOP");

}

- (IBAction)AudioPlayPaused:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"PLAY");
}

- (IBAction)TimeLabelPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"TIMELABEL");

}

- (IBAction)CurrentPlayTimeChanged:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"NEW TIME POS");

}
@end
```

The .m  method where the Subview is added:

```
- (void) addAudio_index:(int)index {
    AudioPlayerViewController *audiov = [[AudioPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    CGRect frame_s = [[[ScrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:[[ScrollView subviews] count]-1] frame];
    CGRect frame = audiov.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame_s.size.height+frame_s.origin.y;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    //[audiov.view setFrame:frame];
    UIView *n =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [ScrollView addSubview:n];
    [n addSubview:audiov.view];
    [audiov.view setHidden:FALSE];


}
```

The Player XIB:
[image]
I thought some hours about but I got no idea about any solution, so maybe you can help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is retaining the `AudioPlayerViewController`s view (and therefore all of the subviews) but it isn't retaining the `audiov` instance. So, when any of the views fire their actions they are calling an instance that has been deallocated.

To resolve, create a property and store the `audiov` (so that it is retained).

Comment: how do I store the audiov? Just put it into an array in the ViewController where the instance exists?

Comment: Doesn't need to be an array, just a property will do: `@property (strong, nonatomic) AudioPlayerViewController *audiov;`

Comment: but the problem is, that there are maybe 2 or 3 audiov inserted

Comment: Ok, in that case, yes, use an array (and when they are removed, remove them from the array).